# How to write regular expression in type script to accept value from 0 to 1000

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, typescript

Html

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendRestItems()">
    <input placeholder="Give point out of 1000  " type="text" class="form-control" 
        name="scores" [(ngModel)]="model.scores" #scores="ngModel"
        max="1000" pattern="^([0-9]{0,3}|1000)" required>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="scores.errors || !disabled" class="buttons">Submit</button>
    <div class="form-control-feedback" *ngIf="scores.errors && (scores.dirty || scores.touched)">
        <p *ngIf="scores.errors.pattern" [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}">score value must be between 0 to 1000</p>
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color':coloring}">{{status}}</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have used angular form to create a input field that would accept value from 0 to 1000, to validate this condition i wrote **regex** as ^([0-9]{0,3}|1000), but this is giving invalid value for 0200,0100 ,etc .
How to resolve this issue,please help me out ?

[Stackbliz_Url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-driven-form-validation-mdtvaw)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular, so I removed the tag. This is just plain JS.

Comment: Use JS validation. `parseInt(value) >= 0 && parseInt(value) <= 100`. Also there is `ng-min` and `ng-max` for `input[type="number"]`

Comment: @Justinas, that allows malformed values. Try `parseInt("100a") >= 0`.

Comment: Using regexp is not a good idea to validate number range.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Regex:

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1000)$

// [0-9] For single digit Number
// [1-9][0-9] For double digit Number
// 1000 final Limit
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexes aren’t needed for this. Use an [`input type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) instead:

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendRestItems()">
    <input placeholder="Give point out of 1000  " type="number" class="form-control" 
        name="scores" [(ngModel)]="model.scores" #scores="ngModel"
        max="1000" min="0" required>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="scores.errors || !disabled" class="buttons">Submit</button>
    <div class="form-control-feedback" *ngIf="scores.errors && (scores.dirty || scores.touched)">
        <p *ngIf="scores.errors.pattern" [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}">score value must be between 0 to 1000</p>
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color':coloring}">{{status}}</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Angular understands this too.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D#input%5Bnumber%5D-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

`^(1000|0?\d{1,3})$`

This expression will allow 1 to 4 digits at all times as long as the number is less than 1000, and leading zeros can be included.

Will match: `0, 0000, 010, 0010, 100, 0100, 1000`

Will not match: `01000, 1001, 2000`

## [Try it here](https://regexr.com/3uv70)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex: `^(100|[1-9]?[0-9])$`

You can also refer to [here for more details](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s07.html)